# How to get time in milliseconds?

Tags: c#

I want to calculate the time of bubble sort algorithm in C#. But it always give 0. This is my code.

```
public void bubbleSort(int[] arr, ref double time)
{
     var sp = new Stopwatch();
     sp.Start();
     int temp = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
     {
          for (int sort = 0; sort < arr.Length - 1; sort++)
          {
               if (arr[sort] > arr[sort + 1])
               {
                    temp = arr[sort + 1];
                    arr[sort + 1] = arr[sort];
                    arr[sort] = temp;
               }
         }  
     }
     sp.Stop();

     time = sp.Elapsed.Milliseconds*1000;
}
```

in main the time is always 0. What mistake i have done in this code.

Comment: Did you debug your code and see `Milliseconds` value?

Comment: If your array isn't really big, then probably your algorithm takes less than 1ms to execute.

Comment: Typically to measure time you run the algortithm some thousands or millions times because often a single iteration takes so little time to be acurately measurable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get `Milliseconds`, you're only getting the millisecond *component* of the time. Thus, 1.0501s will only be listed as 50ms, not 1050.1ms. Also, since this returns an `int`, you will *not* see fractional milliseconds, which may be the case for such a short algorythm.

Instead, use [`TotalMilliseconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will return the entire time in units of milliseconds, as well as retuning a `double` - which includes the fractional parts.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`TotalMilliseconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

> Gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole and fractional milliseconds.

```
time = sp.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds * 1000;
```